# Converting to string not producing required value

Tags: python

I have some code that is using the 'gdshortener' module to produce a shortened version of my source URLS:

```
import simplejson
import httplib2
import twitter
import gdshortener
from random import randint

print("Python will now attempt to submit tweets to twitter...")


try:

    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                      consumer_secret='',
                      access_token_key='',
                      access_token_secret='')

    b = 0

    for a in range(0, 1): #only range 0-1 for this question, actually 1-21
        b = b + 1
        a = randint(1,60000000)
        randint
        print ("a = ", a)
        aa = str(a)


        s1 = gdshortener.ISGDShortener()
        print s1.shorten(url = 'http://audiotechracy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/reviewing-synapse-antidote-rack.html', custom_url = aa)
        ss1 = str(s1)

        status = api.PostUpdate("The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:" + ss1 + " #propellerhead #synapse")



    print("Tweets submitted successfully!")

except Exception,e:
    print str(e)    
    print("Twitter submissions have failed!!!")
```

I am using a random number generator to produce six digit numbers which are then fed to the custom_url parameter of this module. That works fine and I get a series of pseudo-random numbers. However when I try and concatenate my tweet string, my dynamic short URL and some hashtags I get an error that I cannot concatenate string and integer values.

So I have then created the variable 'ss1' which is the string of 's1', however this now produces a tweet like this:

```
The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension:<gdshortener.gdshortener.ISGDShortener object at 0x000000000542AA20> #propellerhead #synapse
```

How can i get it so that the tweet produced is:

```
The new Synapse Antidote Rack Extension: http://is.gd/58077181 #propellerhead #synapse
```

Thanks

Comment: the `ISGDShortener()` method doesn't return an object that can simply be converted to a string. You can look through the API documentation or type `dir(s1)` and view the attributes/methods of the object currently in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked the module and discovered that it returns a tuple. See the following to extract the proper URL.

**Code:**

```
import gdshortener

s1 = gdshortener.ISGDShortener()
x1 = s1.shorten(url='http://audiotechracy.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/reviewing-synapse-antidote-rack.html')[0]
print x1
```

**Result:**

```
http://is.gd/KKxmFd
[Finished in 0.8s]
```

Notice how I added a `[0]` at the end of the `shorten`. This is because `shorten` returns a tuple, which we can index similar to a list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In addition to this, you (user3045351) were trying to print the object `s1` and not the result of the `shorten` method.

Comment: @Human is right. It's kind of like trying to print a function or a generator themselves and not their results. :)

Comment: @nanshi yes, i thought something didn't look right with the way i had coded it. thanks for your help. the only problem i have now is that the 'http://is.gd/' link format triggers a warning from twitter that the above extension is often used for spam or phishing campaigns. i havent thus far found one of the standard url shorteners though who provide an option for customizable urls via their api.